# How to deal with server models and UI models in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

This has been one of my biggest challenges with adapting to angular and I cannot figure out the best way to solve the problem. [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gx011Lap/) has a basic example of a list of user objects that may have come from an API.  Then on the UI, I need some ways of knowing when a user is selected via a checkbox.  Since each user can be selected individually, it makes sense to just add this `isSelected` property to the user model. The only problem is when I try to POST these models back to the server, they have all of these extra UI properties on them still.

Has anyone come up with a clean way to deal with this type of situation? There are more complicated UI's that would use a lot more properties than just `isSelected` and I dont like having to run `delete user['isSelected']` when I want to clean up the models

Comment: You could always use the base model returned to create a working model that you controller uses, and then convert it back on save.

Comment: *"um.. why downvote?"* I can't see your code without going to jsfiddle... I don't necessarily need to see your code in action, i just want to see your code. Though, i guess in this case the code is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: Thats sort of what I am doing already.. I have some `transformRequest` functions that strip away a `UI` property on all my models.  So my working logic all lies underneath the `UI` object on my data model.

Comment: Lol.. well its much easier to deal with code in jsFiddle cause you can manipulate it. figured thats better than no jsFiddle at all

Comment: plus like you said this is an opinion based answer. There are a number of ways to solve it, just haven't found one that I particularly like

Comment: What you could do to automate this is simply loop over the properties of the base original model looking for matching properties in the working model with changed values.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with this solution and so far I think it will work just fine.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function(){
        return {
            'request': function(request) {
                // same as above
                if(request.data){
                    if(request.data.constructor === Array){
                        angular.forEach(request.data, function(obj){
                            delete obj['UI'];
                        });
                    }else if(typeof request.data == 'object'){
                        delete request.data['UI'];
                    }
                }

                return request;
            },

            'response': function(response) {
                // same as above
                if(response.data){
                    if(response.data.constructor === Array){
                        angular.forEach(response.data, function(obj){
                            obj.UI = {};
                        });
                    }else if(typeof response.data == 'object'){
                        response.data.UI = {};
                    }
                }

                return response;
            }
        };
    });
```

In the app config function I am adding these interceptors to each request and response with the server.  I check to see what type of object is being sent and appropriately add/remove the `UI` object.  That way, all object can use the `UI` if needed or just ignore it if an API call doesn't need it.  Then I just attach all my View logic onto the UI object and everything gets cleaned up just fine.

Comment: Why not just have a click event where you pass in the user for that click and then add to an array of selected users, and upon unclicking, you remove the user from the list of selected users?